# PHP Session Unsets Itself

Tags: php, session

my session keeps getting unset, whenever I refresh a page, but when I made a control test it seemed to work fine.

Control(Held data):

```
<?php
session_start();
echo(var_dump($_SESSION));
$_SESSION['name'] = 'john doe';
?>
```

Top of index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo(var_dump($_SESSION));
include('utils/utils.php'); 
?>
```

Login page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('utils.php');
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $email = filter($_POST['email']);
    $password = getPwd(filter($_POST['password']));
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
        if(isAccount($email, $password)){
            $key = genAuthKey();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['auth_key'] = $key;
            mysql_query("update `users` set `auth-key`= '$key' where `email`='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
            print("ok");
        }else {
            print('error');
        }
    }else {     
        print('error');
        logOut();
    }
}else {
print('error');
}
?>
```

The code is getting fired, because it updated the auth-key in the table. I honestly have no idea what the issue is.

Also, the session is unset when I reload the index page.

I've got some more information. The pages can hold session data, and retain it, but once another page using session is loaded, it will unset all data.

Comment: @Steve Just functions, mainly database stuff, nothing to do with session though.

Comment: Do you get session data if you echo `session` just after `print('ok');`

Comment: Ahh, I'll keep looking. On a side note you shouldn't store the users password in a session. Thats a security vulnerability

Comment: @GhazanfarMir `echo($_SESSION);` returns 'Array'.

Comment: echo won't work since it is an array. Please try `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: @GhazanfarMir `Array ( )`
@Steve That was suposed to be 'auth_key', I mistyped. =)

Comment: Your session variable is not being set up properly.. Does it print OK as well? I mean does control fall into the if block at all?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir it was working fine on the other page though.

Comment: Are you by any chance initializing the session and then using a header redirect? (On the same page)

Comment: This `echo(var_dump($_SESSION));` should be `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: No, I'm not using a redirect.

Comment: I've got some more information. The pages can hold session data, and retain it, but once another page using session is loaded, it will unset all data.

Comment: Are you sure the session's unset? Does the `session_id()` stay constant? If it doesn't, then you're getting a fresh new session, and it's likely a cookie setting problem.

Comment: @MarcB the session_id() is staying the same between files, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use Unicode encoded PHP files with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

PHP is not aware of the BOM. The BOM results in an output before your first `<?php` so PHP fails to set the related HTTP header for the session cookie.

From the docs:

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: Depends on the editor you are using... Do you have a hex editor?